# C# Hammock library RestClient.BeginRequest blocks current thread

Tags: c#, rest, asynchronous, callback, blocking

I'm using the awesome Hammock REST library (https://github.com/danielcrenna/hammock) for .NET C#, and I've encountered a problem with RestClient.BeginRequest.  The first time this method gets called in my code, it blocks the current thread for a good 15 seconds.  I was under the impression this method is an asynchronous operation because it returns an IAsyncResult and accepts a callback - it should return immediately, right?

I know the problem is with BeginRequest because a debugging session will show it hanging on that specific line of code - in other words, the problem isn't related to internet connectivity problems or latency between the REST resource and my local machine.

I could dive into the source code for Hammock, but it's pretty confusing in there - has anyone encountered this problem before?  Is this just a bug in Hammock or is it expected behavior?  I'm having a tough time finding much documentation.  Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Is your end point you are connecting to using SSL/TLS? If so, sometimes these delays can be caused by the client attempting to check the revocation list of the SSL certificate.  In .NET you can change the revocation mode using the following code.

```
client.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.NoCheck;
```

I am not sure how you could do this in Hammock.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a property of Dotnet webclient/httprequest, specifically, it seems to do a check for the proxy settings of the machine on the first request.

I've found you can get a big speed up by explicitly setting the proxy in the app.config.  Alternatively you could make your first request on a different thread manually I think.